relation "cache" does not exist in Laravel 11 error for Mews Captcha
SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "cache" does not exist LINE 1: insert into "cache" ("expiration", "key", "value") values ($... ^ (Connection: pgsql, SQL: insert into "cache" ("expiration", "key", "value") values (1729080688, captcha_c00c030403b9cc2f0d81dc7ebb90a683, a:9:{i:0;s:1:"b";i:1;s:1:"p";i:2;s:1:"t";i:3;s:1:"n";i:4;s:1:"r";i:5;s:1:"3";i:6;s:1:"p";i:7;s:1:"m";i:8;s:1:"b";}) on conflict ("key") do update set "expiration" = "excluded"."expiration", "key" = "excluded"."key", "value" = "excluded"."value")
Hi Team can you guide me about Mews Captcha in Laravel 11
1 -I have run composer require mews/captcha
2- php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider" which created config\captcha.php
but when i am run on views its image is broken and when i am trying to open its generated url on next tab it throws error.
Some one help please for laravel 11 because in laravel 11 config/app.php page no providers and aliases is showing to add 'Mews\Captcha\CaptchaServiceProvider'
